# Feature to Raster Conversion: Missing Pixels Near Border

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, convert, arcgis-10.5

I am trying to convert a feature to a raster in ArcGIS 10.5. When I do that, it only keeps the pixels where the centroid falls within the boundary of the featureclass. However, I would like to keep any pixel that touches the boundary. I have tried changing environment settings but nothing seems to help.

In the following image the issue can be visualized:

[image]

Edit: Here are the settings I am using in the Polygon to Raster tool: 
[image]

Comment: Eventually I am going to use the resulting raster to apply raster math to another raster layer. So I am using the same CRS and cell size as that raster layer.

Comment: I don't think the resolution is the issue. I jusst want it to include any pixel touching the boundary. Not just pixels where the centroid is within the boundary.

Comment: Convert raster to points, points to polygons using pointid. Select little squres that intersect your polygons. Perhaps buffer originals first.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Feature to Raster tool help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-to-raster.htm):

> This tool always uses the cell center to decide the value of a raster pixel. If more control over how different types of input feature geometries are to be converted, refer to the respective specific conversion tools: [Point to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/point-to-raster.htm), [Polyline to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/polyline-to-raster.htm), and [Polygon to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/polygon-to-raster.htm).

So use the [Polygon to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/polygon-to-raster.htm) tool.  Specify the "Cell assignment type" parameter as "Maximum area".  Now there's [a trick](https://nicksantos.com/2015/04/quirks-arcgis-snap-rasters-and-converting-polygons-to-rasters/)..., you need to specify a "Priority field" so null values get excluded.

**NOTE:** the priority field must contain numeric values, all of which are > 0.  Any feature where the priority field value is 0 will get treated the same as null so won't fill boundary pixels where the polygon covers less than half of the pixel.

For example (in ArcGIS Pro, but the parameters for this tool are the same in ArcGIS Desktop):

[image]

In the image below, blue pixels were rasterized using Polygon to Raster tool with the above options and red pixels using the Feature to Raster tool / Polygon to Raster tool (with cell centre assignment).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I got the exact same result whether I used Feature to Raster or Polygon to Raster. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I followed your steps completely. I'm in 10.5 but that shouldn't matter. Your blue result is exactly what I need, but the red is what I'm getting no matter what I try.

Comment: @Alicia - see edit (any feature where the priority field value is 0 will get treated the same as null so won't fill boundary pixels)